# Remove event listeners which don't have a function name

Tags: javascript

In the below code there is no function for the event listener . how to remove it . Please help thanks in advance ?.

```
document.getElementById('dob').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
});
```

Comment: select and delete it?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by replacing that element

```
var oldDob = document.getElementById("dob");
var newDob = oldDob.cloneNode(true);
oldDob.parentNode.replaceChild(newDob, oldDob);
```

Comment: we are taking clone of dob object we are dynamically replacing existed object so eventlistners wont work for new object

Comment: Is there any other way to simply stop the eventlistener . i am sorry . i feel the code is too complicated.

Comment: Now i have tried like this :

document.getElementById("dob").removeEventListener('keyup',dob, true);

document.getElementById('dob').addEventListener('keyup', function dob() {
}):

by creating a function name itself. but still not working
});

Comment: In javascript removeEventListener method is there but you need to use named function if you are using anonymous function you have to duplicate that object and need to remove old one that is only the way as of my knowledge